# Crawler para Woocommerce

Tags: php, libcurl, web-crawler, web-scraping

Amigos boa tarde.

Estou desenvolvendo um crawler em php que vai fazer scrapping de alguns urls que vou informar.

Estou tentando fazer ele puxar os valores de uma url dinâmica, mais não estou conseguindo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

```
<?php
$page_title = "MiniCrawler";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title><?php print($page_title) ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php  
// error handling
ini_set('display errors',1);  
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); 


include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

function limpaXml($texto){
    return htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($texto, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}


function dlPage($href) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4");
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Create a DOM object
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $dom->load($str);

    return $dom;
    }

// Settings on tophttp://www.dafiti.com.br/special-price/
$sitesToCheck = array(
                    // id is the page ID for selector
    array(

        "url" => "http://www.adidas.com.br/homem-outlet?sz=48","categoria" => "adidas" , "selector" => "div#product-grid div.product-tile div.hockeycard div.innercard"
        )


);
$savePath = "json/";
$emailContent = "";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

// For every page to check...
foreach($sitesToCheck as $site) {

    $url = $site["url"];
    if (!empty($url)){
        //$numProdutos = dlPage($url);
        //$numTotal = $numProdutos->find("p.count");
        //$pag = 48;
        //(int)(((int)$numTotal[0]->plaintext)/96);
        $total = 432; 
        $porPag = 48;
        $pag = $total / $porPag;


        //$numProdutos->clear();
        //unset($numProdutos);
        for ($i=24;$i>$pag;){

            $valorFinal = $porPag + $i + $i;
            $novaUrl = $url."&start=".$valorFinal;
            $novoSite = $xml->addChild('website');
            $novoSite->addChild('webUrl', $novaUrl);
            $novoSite->addChild('categoria', $site["categoria"]);
            //var_dump($site);
            // Calculate the cachedPage name, set oldContent = "";
            $fileName = strtolower($site["categoria"]);
            $oldContent = "";
            // Get the URL's current page content
            $html = dlPage($novaUrl);
                if (!empty($html)){
                    $produtos = $novoSite->addChild('produtos');
                    $total=0; 
                    // Find content by querying with a selector, just like a selector engine!
                    foreach($html->find($site["selector"]) as $element) {
                        if(isset($element)){
                            $link = $element->find('div.image a', 0);
                                $img = $element->find('div.image a img.show', 0);
                            if(!empty($element->find('div.product-info-wrapper', 0)->plaintext)){
                                $produto['marca'] = $site["categoria"]; //$element->find('div.product-box-brand', 0)->plaintext; 
                                $produto['titulo'] = limpaXml($element->find('div.clearfix a span.title', 0)->plaintext);
                                $produto['preco_old'] = $element->find('div.clearfix div.price span.strike', 0)->plaintext;
                                $produto['preco'] = $element->find('div.clearfix div.price span.salesprice', -1)->plaintext;
                                //$produto['preco'] = $element->find('span.product-box-price-from', 0)->plaintext;

                                $produto['url'] = htmlspecialchars($link->href);
                                $produto['imagem'] = $img->getAttribute('data-original');
                                //$json[] = json_encode($produto);
                                $produtoNovo = $produtos->addChild('produto');
                                $produtoNovo->addChild('titulo',$produto['titulo']);
                                $produtoNovo->addChild('marca',$produto['marca']);
                                $produtoNovo->addChild('preco',$produto['preco']);
                                $produtoNovo->addChild('preco_old',$produto['preco_old']);
                                $produtoNovo->addChild('url',$produto['url']);
                                $produtoNovo->addChild('imagem',$produto['imagem']);
                                echo "$novoSite";
                                echo  '<div style="float:left; width=300px; border:1px solid #000; padding:10px;"><a href="'.$produto['url'].'"><img src="'.$produto['imagem'].'"></a><br><p>Nome do Produto: '.$produto['titulo'].'</p><p>Marca: '.$produto['marca'].'</p><p>Preço Antigo: '.$produto['preco_old'].'</p><p>Preço: '.$produto['preco'].'</p><p>URL: '.$novaUrl.'</p></div>';
                                //echo 'Nome do Produto: '.$produto['titulo'].'<br />';
                                $total++;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                //Header('Content-type: text/xml');
                $arquivo = $xml->asXML();
                // Save new content
                file_put_contents($savePath.$fileName.'.xml',$arquivo);

                $html->clear();
                unset($html);
            $i = $i;


        }

    }

}



// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL


/*
$html = file_get_html('http://www.dafiti.com.br/Sandalia-Anabela-DAFITI-SHOES-Caramelo-1746512.html');

// Find all "A" tags and print their HREFs
/*foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    echo $e->href . '<br>';
}*/

// Retrieve all images and print their SRCs
/*foreach($html->find('a.gallery-thumb[data-img-zoom]') as $e)
    echo '<img src="'.$e . '"><br>';

// Find all anchors and images 


// Find all images, print their text with the "<>" included
/*foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
*/
// Find the DIV tag with an id of "myId"
//foreach($html->find('div#myId') as $e)
  //  echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// Find all SPAN tags that have a class of "myClass"
/*foreach($html->find('div.detail-row') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// Find all TD tags with "align=center"
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';



/*
$target_url = "http://www.eleshop.com.br/";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);


foreach($html->find('img') as $link){
echo '<img src="'. $link->src.'"><br />';
}
*/
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bem você não disse porque não esta conseguindo existe vários poréns como acessar a URL, ler o conteúdo e etc., mas a principio diria que fazer algo assim é bem complexo, trabalhoso e ilegal dependendo do que está pegando e se o cara mudar algo do que esta pegando ou bloquear seu IP já era então ... para não dizer que não dei uma alternativa já pensou em usar algum servido próprio para isso tipo [Import.io](https://www.import.io)

Comment: Diego. Obrigado.